# Android NullPointerException at android.view.ViewConfiguration

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm getting a NullPointerException:

```
public void llenardatos(SQLiteDatabase db, int pos) {

    ImgVector = new ImageView[50];
    String[] id = new String[] { String.valueOf(pos + 1) }; 

    EditText txttipo = (EditText) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.Txttipo);
    EditText spalto = (EditText) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.Txtalto);
    EditText splargo = (EditText) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.TxtLargo);
    EditText spancho = (EditText) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.Txtancho);
    EditText sobser = (EditText) mContentView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtobservaciones);
    EditText sphora = (EditText) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.Txthora);
    EditText txtfecha = (EditText) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.txtfecha);
    TextView txtlati = (TextView) mContentView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtlatitud);
    TextView txtlongi = (TextView) mContentView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtlongitud);

    Critico cr = new Critico();
    cr.seleccionar(db, id);
    txttipo.setText("" + cr.getTipo());
    spalto.setText("" + cr.getAlto());
    splargo.setText("" + cr.getLargo());
    spancho.setText("" + cr.getAncho());
    sobser.setText("" + cr.getObservaciones());
    sphora.setText(cr.getHora());
    txtfecha.setText("" + cr.getFecha());
    txtlati.setText("" + cr.getLatitud());
    txtlongi.setText("" + cr.getLongitud());

    FotoCritico fc = new FotoCritico();
    ArrayList<String> datos = fc.seleccionartodos(db, id);
    int i = datos.size();
    for (int contador = 0; contador < i; contador++) {
        String dato = datos.get(contador);
        Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(dato);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                500, 250, 1f);
        ImgVector[contador] = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImgVector[contador].setLayoutParams(lparams4);
        ImgVector[contador].setImageResource(R.drawable.fotoandroid);
        ImgVector[contador].setId(contador);
        ImgVector[contador].setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
        lyn.addView(ImgVector[contador]);
        // personas++;
        ImgVector[contador].setImageURI(imgUri);
    }
}
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException:

```
04-25 08:39:57.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 08:39:57.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3358): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 08:39:57.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3358):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:276)
```

Eclipse is not reporting a syntax error.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Keep debug point at FragConsultaCritico.java at line number 108 and check which one is getting null by placing your cursor on all the used variables in that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A java.lang.NullPointerException happens when you try to access an object that has the value null.  The variable 'lyn', or 'ImgVector[contador]' has the value null when when you are trying to use it.

To find out which variable has the value null, put some if statements in there:

```
if (lyn == null)
  Log.d("error", "lyn has null");

if (ImgVector[contador] == null)
  Log.d("error", "ImgVector[contador] has null");
```

Put these lines throughout the code, and the if statement should evaluate to true, and this will be the spot where you need to make sure the variables are instantiated.